# Binding issues with toolkit:MultiselectList Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

So I have been working on a windows phone 8 app and I have some issues with Binding data to toolkit:MultiselectList. The XAML I have is

```
<toolkit:MultiselectList x:Name="CatCardList">
    <toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Tap="ListItemTap" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120">
                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="{Binding accent}"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding limit}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding alert}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:MultiselectList.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:MultiselectList>
```

I am inserting elements of a class which has the following elements (all public with appropriate get and set)

```
string name
string limit
string alert
SolidColorBrush accent
```

When the element is inserted I am only seeing the ToString() of that class in the list because the binding is not applied. If on the other hand I use the `ListBox` control with the same binding then everything works fine.

Another interesting fact is that when I had NuGet 2.0, the above binding worked fine. But I updated the NuGet package today and since then it has stopped working and I get an `Invalid XAML` warning, but it compiles fine.

I have no idea why this is not working when it used to work before. Can someone please tell me as to whether this is a bug with the NuGet package or is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a minimal and indepdent repro for your issue. In the meanwhile, while I'm not sure it's releated, for WP8 it's recommended you use the new LongListMultiSelector and not WP7's MultiselectList. See code sample @ http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336298

Comment: @JustinAngel Thanks a lot. Switching to LongListMultiSelector solved the issue.

Comment: Is there anything else you did to solve this? I am also having this problem, but it still persists after switching to LongListMultiSelector.

Comment: @mbmccormick I didn't have to do anything else

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems, I fixed those problems by using the new Long List multi selector control available on the windows phone 8 sdk...

It should fix all your problems!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the WindowsPhone 8 project of Phone toolkit doesn't include style defintion for MultiselectList,
copy the style defintion with TargetType"controls:MultiselectList" from WindowsPhone 7 project to Themes/Generic.xaml should work.